# What bonuses are gotten from Mass Effect: Infiltrator?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-infiltrator

I recently got Mass Effect: Infiltrator, Mainly waiting for ME3 to come out, I haven't completed it yet, nor do I have ME3, but I would like to know what weapons you get from beating the campaign....

I know about the Intel (as it is mentioned everywhere I look).

However when I look for information on the 'exclusive weapons' all I can find is that there are some ... not which ones they are.

I'm not looking for a detailed description, heck I would settle for "You get a sniper rifle", I just wanna know more than what I currently do....

Can someone help?

Comment: I also failed to find a list of weapons gained...

Comment: At least im not the only one...

Comment: Is it possible that it means exclusive weapons within the game (like, the Beam Gun, which is exclusive to Infiltrator), and not guns for ME3 which are exclusively unlocked via Infiltrator?

Comment: No it means for use in ME3, this is an extract taken from the ME wiki itself "Throughout each mission, the player can collect intel points which can be uploaded to Mass Effect 3's Galaxy at War system to increase the Galactic Readiness rating or for in-game credits. **The game will also allow players to unlock exclusive weapons for use in Mass Effect 3.**"

Comment: @SamuelStandrin [This comment on the Mass Effect Wiki article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Mass_Effect:_Infiltrator#Unlocks_as_result_of_beating_game.) and the cited [video interview](http://www.gamespot.com/mass-effect-infiltrator/videos/mass-effect-infiltrator-interview-with-jarrad-trudgen-6364875/), not to mention my own playthrough, say otherwise.  Submitting an answer.

Comment: Someone needs to change the wiki then because that is **too** misleading...

Comment: @SamuelStandrin Just did!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no weapon unlocks for Mass Effect 3, that was misinformation.  All you can earn for Mass Effect 3 are War Assets for completing Infiltrator and points toward your Galactic Readiness rating by uploading Cerberus intel.

Source: [Video interview with Mass Effect Infiltrator design director Jarrad Trudgen.](http://www.gamespot.com/mass-effect-infiltrator/videos/mass-effect-infiltrator-interview-with-jarrad-trudgen-6364875/) Relevant information at 3:04.